# How do I find the 'd' in RSA (euclidean algorithm)?

Tags: rsa

In this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mf7x9IiJndY

At 13:25 he shows that I should do the next row:

> 7 X d = 1(mod 160)

I didnt understook how did he get the 'd' from it?
He said somthing aboud euclidean algorithem. But all "euclidean algorithem" said is what the "GCD" of some two numbers..
After some reserch I found "extended algorithm" too, But I dont see how does this algorithem can help me too.

What are the steps here to find the 'd' and what is connection to "euclidean algorithm"?

Comment: Have you tried to research something except of this video? You have all of the keywords needed.

Comment: this Q belongs here : http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes of course! the most close thing I found is that video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fz1vxq5ts5I but she didnt explained well the all steps so I lost myself somwhere in the middle

Comment: read this https://mathblag.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/euclidean_algorithm/

Comment: I would tell you that wikipedia has a detailed explanation of the extended euclidean algorithm except wikipedia is a state secret: nobody is supposed to know about it.